# NextJS 13 <button onClick={}> Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

[image: NextJS Error Message]

Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.

^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.

```
const reqHelp = () => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '1',
        text: '1',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
    })
}
```

```
return(
        <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={reqHelp} className="stopwatchButton">Request Help</button>
        </div>
);
```

Search NextJS 13 Official Document and about Server/Client Render

Comment: Have you tried converting that component to a client component, i.e. add `'use client';` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Add

```js
'use client';
```

on top of the file where you are using `handleClick` because all components in Next 13 by default are server components, therefore for client side interactivity you need to use [`use client`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive).

Comment: But then you instantly run into issues because NextJS has issues rendering async components ..argggh

Comment: Yeah, you can't just use fetch in Client Components. NextJS recommends using a data-fetching library like SWR or React Query https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#use-in-client-components

Comment: This seems like a backward step. I believe you could bind click handlers in server components in Next 12 (using getStaticProps).

Comment: @darKnight previously with gsp/gssp/isr you could choose only a single hydration method for the entire route/page.tsx. now with server components you can choose hydration methods at component level without think about it at the route level.

also with server components you have the ability to fallback to a loading state with suspense, but with gssp you had to wait (got white screen, even worse with cold starts, i have seen it go as high as 20 seconds) for the entire page to get server rendered.

Comment: By the way, prevent client components from being async functions.
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-async-client-component

Comment: @xgqfrms async client components would eventually be supported(probably with react forget) in a future RFC https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/first-class-promises/text/0000-first-class-support-for-promises.md#why-cant-client-components-be-async-functions

Answer (score 11):

Client components can be imported into server components, but not the other way around, this allows us to create **server** or **client** components at the component level.

For example let's say we have an offending piece of code like a button in an **async server component** that throws errors due to implementing the `onClick` event handler, we can extract the button into it's own **client component** by adding the `"use client"` annotation at the very first line of the new button component, that way we can still use `await` in the our **async server component** and then import the button as a **client component**.

[Read more on composing client and server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#composing-client-and-server-components)

Answer (score 1):

that is true that you cannot pass event handlers as prop to a client component but the only exception is server actions. [from docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions):

> Props
>
> In some cases, you might want to pass down a Server Action to a Client
> Component as a prop.

```
 <ClientComponent myAction={updateItem} />
```

Answer (score 1):

if use want to use onclick with server component, you can split the actions to component and add "use client" on top of file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  from next/link instead if you'd like to keep using server side component.

```
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={"/test"} />
```

You can do something free on a new page /test.

Comment: You cannot add an onClick handler to a Link component in a React Server Component. You would need to create a new client component with 'use client' at the top and then import that to the server component

Comment: @C-Dev YES YOU CAN use Link component on server component as in a new page. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link